# Nand2Tetris Not16.hdl

Tags: hdl, nand2tetris

I cannot figure why my Not16.hdl is failing the test script.

```
CHIP Not16 {
IN in[16];
OUT out[16];

PARTS:
Not(in=in[0], out=out[0]);
Not(in=in[1], out=out[1]);
Not(in=in[2], out=out[2]);
Not(in=in[3], out=out[3]);
Not(in=in[4], out=out[4]);
Not(in=in[5], out=out[5]);
Not(in=in[6], out=out[6]);
Not(in=in[7], out=out[7]);
Not(in=in[8], out=out[8]);
Not(in=in[9], out=out[9]);
Not(in=in[10], out=out[10]);
Not(in=in[11], out=out[11]);
Not(in=in[12], out=out[12]);
Not(in=in[13], out=out[13]);
Not(in=in[14], out=out[14]);
Not(in=in[15], out=out[15]);
```

}

Test Script:

```
load Not16.hdl,
output-file Not16.out,
compare-to Not16.cmp,
output-list in%B1.16.1 out%B1.16.1;

set in %B0000000000000000,
eval,
output;

set in %B1111111111111111,
eval,
output;

set in %B1010101010101010,
eval,
output;

set in %B0011110011000011,
eval,
output;

set in %B0001001000110100,
eval,
output;
```

Errors on Hardware Simulator:

- 'Comparison failure on Line 2'
- 'Comparison failure on Line 4'
- 'Comparison failure on Line 5'

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: I do not have my reference materials handy but it occurs to me that in and out may be reserved words. Try changing them to inbits and outbits and see if that helps.